# What is your toolset?

Tags: tools

What tools, free or otherwise do you use to help you with your "webmastering"

I'm thinking along the lines of, Link checking, analytics, web stats, page validation, plus anything else you can think of!

Personally I use: [webmasters tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), [AWstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net)

I'm looking for anything (free or paid) which maybe hovering under my radar which could be of use.

Answer (score 4):

## Developing:

Software:

- Zend Development Environment
- [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)
- EditPlus if needed
- Photoshop

Front-end frameworks/etc:

- [CSS3pie](http://www.css3pie.com)
- [html5boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com)
- [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel)
- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) + [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)
- Where needed: jQuery

Browsers:

- Chrome + [EyeDropper](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka) (colorpicker) plugin
- FireFox + [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)
- FireFox second install [emulating iPad](http://www.labnol.org/internet/test-websites-on-ipad/13368/)
- IE8 and IE9beta
- Opera
- Safari

Sites:

- [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
- [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com)
- [CSS3.info](http://css3.info)
- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com)
- [CSS3 Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)
- [CSS minifier](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/)

## SEO:

- [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)
- [Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/?pli=1)
- SEOmoz [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/)
- [Yahoo Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/)
- Google PR Toolbar

## Comic relief and other distractions

(VERY important to get your mind off of the code once in a while)

- [CSSsquirrel](http://www.cssquirrel.com/comic/)
- [Dilbert](http://www.dilbert.com/)
- [Cyanide & Happiness](http://www.explosm.net/comics/)
- a movie trivia quiz

Comment: Links where you can perhaps?

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated now :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com) for development. Version 1.5 + PHP addon has great PHP support, not to mention great HTML/CSS/JavaScript support.

Graphic design I use [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/compare/).

For debugging I use common sense, late nights, and [bookmarklets](http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/mobileperfbkm.php), which include:

- DOM MONSTER!
- cssess
- Zoompf
- Mobile Perf

Comment: I've been using Aptana 2, which has very bad PHP support (due to the fact it's using PDT in my opinion) however, if you use the update from 1.5 it works very nicely.